# Размытие границ input из-за transform: translate

Tags: css, transform

[image: Формы]

Есть форма (скрин). Чтобы выровнять её по вертикали и горизонтали я применяю свойство `transform: translate(-50%, -50%)`. До него естественно `position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%`. Но почему-то свойство transform затрагивает инпуты внутри формы и кнопку "Войти". Инпуты размываются до 2px, а у кнопки появляются отступы по 1px, хотя она должна растягиваться на 100%. Как это можно исправить? Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что, чтобы вам помогли выложите разметку и покажите, что да как вы питались...  В данном случае, скрин не лучший вариант...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скорее всего, из-за несовпадения пикселей. Возможно у вас общая ширина/высота нечетная. Т.е. 203px - тогда идёт сбой

Вот посмотрите на wrapper. Поменяйте на четное число, и всё станет четко

```
.wrapper {
  width: 203px;
  height: 203px;
  padding: 20px;

  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rJWVWR

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Помогло)